# How do I make a rollover for a button with NO CSS or javascript?

Tags: html

So basically I have zero ability to use CSS or javascript because it's blocked by the site I'm trying to work on from a higher administration level offsite with permissions I can't be granted because we outsource our site's main development so I have limited editing options (idk if anyone has ever worked on a site by dealer.com without working for them but it's... limiting). I  can only use a bit of bootstrap and HTML.

I want to make the button have an onmouseover and onmouseout effect but thus far have had zero luck.

Normally I'd do this in CSS and it would be fine but basically any script gets a big angry, "nope you can't, security risk!!! Red flag!!! Abort!!" popup when you save.

`<a class="btn btn-default" style="color:white; background-color: var(--color-electric-vivid);" href="/ev-enquiry.htm" target="_blank">Enquire Here</a>` I'm relegated to somehow getting a hover effect into this. My options are limited and I'm at a loss.

Do I just give up or does anyone have some sort of brilliant recommendation that will somehow work?

[picture of button I'm trying to make pretty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMv55.png)

Edit for clarity: I do not have the ability to go into the main head or body of the HTML. I can change the contents of a div from a wordpress style textbox and it does not let me use javascript or CSS. I don't love it but that's my option so I'm looking for a workaround in HTML as that is genuinely the only thing I can use in this case.

Comment: Are you able to use internal `<style>` tags in the `<head>` element within the HTML document rather than a file linking to it?

Comment: I unfortunately can only edit the HTML within divs generated by the site. I can basically drag and drop a container onto the site and all I can change is what's inside of that.

Basically I'm bound to something not dissimilar to this comment box. I can change what's inside of the comment box but can't change anything within ```<head>``` or basically any important part of the body. 

I'm doing what I can with a very limiting platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very little JS but you can try to do this:

```
<button href="#" onmouseover="this.style.color='orange';" onmouseout="this.style.color='';">Button</button>
```

Comment: He said NO JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried Javascript and it gives me an error about how I can't use Javascript in case of malicious code.

Comment: I tried it because I'm desperate and inexplicably it seems to be allowing that after all so I guess it's not all Javascript it just has a very low bar as to what it disallows...

I'll play around with it and choose that answer if the site chooses to cooperate with it after all.